# ¿Cómo elimino las tres primeras letras de una lista de cada uno de los elementos?

Tags: python

Intento borrar de una lista los tres primeros números/letras con la función `str(x[:3])`:

```
lista=['Jueves1', '2martes', '30miércoles', 'Jueves23']
resultado=lista[3:]
print(resultado)
```

Si lo hago con un solo elemento de la lista, sí lo elimina:

```
un_solo_elemento=['Jueves1']
resultado=un_solo_elemento[3:]
print(resultado)
```

Mi cuestión aquí es, ¿cómo puedo hacer esto para cada uno de los elementos que se encuentran dentro de la lista? De tal modo que me imprima: `['ves1', 'rtes', 'iércoles', 'ves23']`

De antemano muchas gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con un solo elemento puedes, por que ese elemento ha dejado de ser una lista y se ha transformado en una cadena, y el "slice" o recorte funciona distinto para una lista. Lo que puedes hacer es implementar un ciclo para iterar por cada elemento y hacer el recorte de cada cadena, mediante una [comprensión de listas](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) puedes generar una nueva lista de acuerdo al requerimiento:

```
lista=['Jueves1', '2martes', '30miércoles', 'Jueves23']

nueva_lista = [e[3:] for e in lista]

print(nueva_lista)

['ves1', 'rtes', 'iércoles', 'ves23']
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, de hecho estoy estudiando justamente ese tema, de comprensión de listas. Por eso me surgió la duda de este ejercicio específicamente. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Otra forma usando [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) y una [función anónima](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions):

```
nueva_lista = list(map(lambda x:x[3:], lista))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a checar